# Why is my delta time constantly under 1 millisecond?

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-loop, timing

I have a game loop that looks like this:

```
while (Sync())
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

The sync function computes my delta time like this:

```
bool Sync()
{
     EndTime = GetTime();
     DeltaTime = (EndTime - StartTime) / TimerFreq
     StartTime = EndTime

}
```

However the delta time I compute is not correct. The DeltaTime should be in milliseconds but I always end up with less than 1 millisecond... Clearly this is not right.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be right? If DoStuff() takes less than 1ms, it is correct, isn't it? The error is not in provided code part.

Comment: 1 ms? I think I may be behind the times....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it is right.**

Computers are really fast nowadays and you are not computing anything in DoStuff enough expensive to expend more than 1ms.